# Event not Bubbling to Parent Element from Child Element

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, event-bubbling

I read the article on https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing about Bubbling.

According to the article, the following event on the `article` tag with `id="article"` should have *bubbled* to the `<p id="para"></p>`, inside which article is nested.

```js
    let para = document.getElementById("para");
    let article = document.getElementById("article");

    /*
    article.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("I'm an article tag!");
    });
    */
    para.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("I'm a p tag!");
    });
```

```html
        <p id="para">
            <article id="article">Click Me!</article>
        </p>
```

However, absolutely, nothing happens. The Event listener on `article` works just fine(when not commented out). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. An `<article>` can't be a child of a `<p>` - check out the rendered HTML:

```js
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="para">
  <article id="article">Click Me!</article>
</p>
```

As a result, the browser *ends* the `<p id="para">` when the `<article>` tag begins - so they're no longer parent and child, but siblings.

(The `<p>` tag can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), which the `<article>` tag is [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article))

Make sure your HTML passes [validation first](https://validator.w3.org/).

If you used something else valid - like a `<span>` - it'd work:

```js
let para = document.getElementById("para");
let article = document.querySelector("span");

/*
article.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("I'm an article tag!");
});
*/
para.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("I'm a p tag!");
});
```

```html
<p id="para">
  <span id="article">Click Me!</span>
</p>
```