# why event bubling do not work with tags h1 h2 ... Can you tell me why?

Tags: javascript, html

in my body i used these tags

```css
div { outline: 1px solid black; }
h1  { outline: 1px solid navy; }
h2  { outline: 1px solid blue; }
h3  { outline: 1px solid cyan; }
p   { outline: 1px solid pink; }
```

```html
<div class="DIV" onclick="alert(1)">DIV
  <h1 class="h1" onclick="alert(2)">H1
    <h2 class="h2" onclick="alert(3)">H2
      <h3 class="h3" onclick="alert(4)">H3
        <p class="p" onclick="alert(5)">P</p>
      </h3>
    </h2>
  </h1>
</div>
```

i wanted to see 1 2 3 4 5 but i saw 5 4 1

When i used only tag div it worked: 5 4 3 2 1

```css
div { outline: 1px solid black; }
div > div  { outline: 1px solid navy; }
div > div > div { outline: 1px solid blue; }
div > div > div > div  { outline: 1px solid cyan; }
div > div > div > div > p { outline: 1px solid pink; }
```

```html
<div class="DIV" onclick="alert(1)">DIV
  <div class="h1" onclick="alert(2)">H1
    <div class="h2" onclick="alert(3)">H2
      <div class="h3" onclick="alert(4)">H3
        <p class="p" onclick="alert(5)">P</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was looking for information, but I didn't find anything about it

Comment: You can't nest `<h1><h2>...` elements, so I speculate the differences in behaviour might be due to how the HTML spec requires browsers to normalize invalid HTML.

Comment: See the _permitted content_ for `<h1>–<h6>` ~ [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event not Bubbling to Parent Element from Child Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69998023/283366)